# About creating new google play developer account

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I'm a beginner-level Android developer, I want to create a Google Play developer account for myself. But the problem is I don't have any credit cards to pay $25 to create the account. But my elder brother has a credit card.

**Can I use my brother's card to pay the registration fee?**

Also, I heard something about a new policy update from Google Play, should I worry about it? I'm from Bangladesh and it's really hard to get passports and credit cards. I have my National ID card, I assume it is needed for the account verification.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a US$25 one-time registration fee that you can pay using either a debit card or credit card. The cards which are accepted by Google Play Console are Visa, American Express, Mastercard, etc. but prepaid cards are not accepted depending on where you are (location).

Go ahead and register using this link [Google Developer Console Link](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/signup) and yes you can use you brother's card for as long as its part of those accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any credit card you should have valid authorisation for the card that you are going to use.

Google is charging lifetime fees of $25.

Happy developing Apps for Android !!

Best of luck

Comment: Thank you but I don't quite understand about the valid authorization part. The type of the credit card that I want to use, that is fulfilled the requirements from Google. Isn't that enough? Or I need any authorization from the bank or something?

Comment: There is nothing "lifetime" about it. `Lifetime` would imply that it is a fee a developer would pay "once in a lifetime", and that would be it, they would never again during their life need to pay said fee.  Google lied to you about this. What they really meant was "one time fee until your account goes inactive after 180 days".  Let me remind you, 180 days is EXTREMELY opposite of "Lifetime". A “bait and switch” is a scam to mislead developers, whereby Google advertises an appealing but ingenuine offer to sell a service that Google does not actually intend to honor (i.e. "Lifetime").